# Отловить изменение размера блока

Tags: jquery

Как отловить изменение размера блока, если он задается внутренним содержимым?

Comment: конкретнее - в результате чего изменятся размеры блока?

Answer (score 1):

Можно привязать обработчик на события `DOMNodeInserted`, `DOMNodeRemoved` и `DOMSubtreeModified`.

```
$('#myDiv').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    // Имяенилось содержимое блока, возможно, изменился размер
});
```

Не сработает в IE.

Источник: [Fire jQuery event on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change).

Comment: Во-первых и в Опере, а во-вторых лучше использовать метод .on()